# Discord JavaScript bot doesn't reply

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

After browsing for hors, I finally made my Discord bot, but in the meme section, when I am typing a command, the bot doesn't replies.

Here's the code-

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});


//const meme = await fetch('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme').then(response => response.json());

const jokes = [
  'I went to a street where the houses were numbered 8k, 16k, 32k, 64k, 128k, 256k and 512k. It was a trip down Memory Lane.',
  '“Debugging” is like being the detective in a crime drama where you are also the murderer.',
  'The best thing about a Boolean is that even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit.',
  'A programmer puts two glasses on his bedside table before going to sleep. A full one, in case he gets thirsty, and an empty one, in case he doesn’t.',
  'If you listen to a UNIX shell, can you hear the C?',
  'Why do Java programmers have to wear glasses? Because they don’t C#.',
  'What sits on your shoulder and says “Pieces of 7! Pieces of 7!”? A Parroty Error.',
  'When Apple employees die, does their life HTML5 in front of their eyes?',
  'Without requirements or design, programming is the art of adding bugs to an empty text file.',
  'Before software can be reusable it first has to be usable.',
  'The best method for accelerating a computer is the one that boosts it by 9.8 m/s2.',
  'I think Microsoft named .Net so it wouldn’t show up in a Unix directory listing.',
  'There are two ways to write error-free programs; only the third one works.',
            ];

const hi = [
  'I\'m not of your age that you\'ll say me hello!!',
  'I don\'t talk with pigs!\n',
  'Don\'t disturb me!\nI am not your friend!!'         
           ];

            
const newstype=[
  'Do you really think this are good news?\n',
  'News always tells truth.\n',
  'Read the news carefully, who knows, maybe the news is about you...',
         ]



const prefix = "";
async function asyncCall()
{
  client.on("message", function(message) 
  { 
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    switch (message.content) 
        {
        case "Hello One Eye JS":
            //message.reply(" I\'m beeta");
          message.channel.send(hi[Math.floor(Math.random() * hi.length)]);
        break;

        case "Crack a joke":
          message.channel.send("Let\'s crack it!!")
          message.channel.send(jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length)]);
          break;

        case "Who are you?":
          message.channel.send("I am the one whom you see everyday in front of the mirror!");
        break

        case "Tell me some news":
          const total =message.author.username;
          const news = [
            (total+' may be dead in one hour\n'),
            'Ultron can come here and extract Vibranium in any moment\n',
            'The sky would be filled with pigs anytime between 6.0.0 a.m to 6.0.1 a.m\n',
            'People may turn to zombies tonight\n',
            ('Mojang stated that '+total+'\'s Minecraft account may be banned permanently.\n'),
            'some Discord accounts are now potential target for hackers\n',
            'Peoples are not advised to go outside today because meteorologists have detected that there would be rain of eggs. \n',
                      ]
          message.channel.send(newstype[Math.floor(Math.random() * newstype.length)]);
          message.channel.send(news[Math.floor(Math.random() * news.length)]);
        break;

        case "Show me some memes":
          message.channel.send("MEMEY.....MEMEY.....MEMEY......\n")
          const subReddits = ["memes"];
          const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];
          const url = `https://www.imgur.com/r/${random}/hot.json`;
          const res =  fetch(url);
          const json =  res.json();
          const posts = json.data.filter(f => msg.channel.nsfw || !f.nsfw);

          if (!posts.length) return message.channel.send("No posts, maybe try in a nsfw channel");
          const post = posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)];
          const redditUrl = `https://www.reddit.com${post.reddit}`;
          const MemeEmbed = 
          {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            url: 'https://www.reddit.com${post.reddit}',
            image: 
            {
              url: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
            },
          }
          message.channel.send({ embeds: [MemeEmbed] });
        break;
      }                                          
  });  
} 

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I have given my bot full permission to send and receive texts. But still the problem persists. I have rejoined the bot, but still, it shows the sam.

Any idea why this error hapens?

(*The Bot does not throw any exception.*)

Comment: Why do you wrap you event listener inside a function? Try taking the event outside or calling the `asyncCall` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped the event listener `<Discord.Client>.on` inside the async function `asyncCall` but you're not calling that function anywhere in your code so obviously that even listener will not work.

To solve your problem, remove the `asyncCall` function and place the event listener in a global scope, or just call the function `asyncCall()`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

// declare variables etc

client.on('message', () => {
// do your stuff here
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: if this helped could you consider marking it as a correct answer?